# Can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str [TypeError]

Tags: python-3.x

I am not too knowledgable in Python however i have imported an old project from github and trying to fix it but am getting this last error when trying to load a model asset. I'm sure its hiding in plain sight. The line number it refers to is: string += byte

```
def ReadNullTerminatedString(f):
    byte = f.read(1)
    string = ""
    while struct.unpack('B', byte)[0] != 0:
        string += byte
        byte = f.read(1)

    return string
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 the string is no more a byte string like in Python 2, so it is necessary to change "" to b"" in `string = ""` (or best **rename `string` to `byte_array = b""` as string is not a good identifier in Python 3**) .

The code below demonstrates what is the problem about:

```
s1 = ""
s2 = b"a"
# s3 = s1 + s2 # TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
s1 = b""
s2 = b"a"
s3 = s1 + s2 # works OK
```

So the code you provided should be:

```
def ReadNullTerminatedString(f):
    byte = f.read(1)
    byte_array = b""
    while struct.unpack('B', byte)[0] != 0:
        byte_array += byte
        byte = f.read(1)

    return byte_array
```

The code below  does not throw any error and prints the right result:

```
import struct
f = open('abc_0.bin', 'wb')
f.write(b'abc\x00')
f.close()
f = open('abc_0.bin','rb') 
# ^-- contains b'abc\x00' i.e. 'abc' followed by NUL
def ReadNullTerminatedString(f):
    byte = f.read(1)
    byte_array = b""
    while struct.unpack('B', byte)[0] != 0:
        byte_array += byte
        byte = f.read(1)
    return byte_array
print( ReadNullTerminatedString(f) ) # gives b'abc'
```

By the way: also

```
def ReadNullTerminatedString(f):
    byte = f.read(1)
    byte_array = b""
    while byte != b'\x00': # struct.unpack('B', byte)[0] != 0:
        byte_array += byte
        byte = f.read(1)
    return byte_array
```

works OK, so there is no need for `struct.unpack()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however the error is still persisting pointing to the same line except with a second line further down that reads: ReadNullTerminatedString(f)

Comment: Can you provide the code for opening the file and the code with the  second line further down so that I can reproduce what you speak about?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/t11b3v0W   lines 297 and 410

Comment: See updated answer ... the improved code works for me OK ... Hmmm ...

Comment: I suggest you make sure you run the changed code not the old one ...

Comment: I can't see in the entire code you provided with the link any reason for throwing an error after the change. Can you provide the exact error message? And check if you run the right file?

Comment: Perhaps it's a problem im having with the Maya program instead, the console repeats this message: # Error: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
# # Traceback (most recent call last):
# #   File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
# #   File "C:\Users/Delta/Documents/maya/2023/scripts\CoDMayaTools.py", line 410, in ImportXModel
# #     ReadNullTerminatedString(f)
# #   File "C:\Users/Delta/Documents/maya/2023/scripts\CoDMayaTools.py", line 297, in ReadNullTerminatedString
# #     string += byte
# # TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Comment: From ReadNullTerminatedString # # string += byte # # TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str you CAN SEE that the change you have done to the file is **NOT** in the Error message. You run a file without the changed line 297 !!! You have edited the wrong file which is not run by the Maya program.

Comment: sorry for all the trouble, but i still dont understand what i should be changing here :/?

Comment: You should change the code in the file which throw the Error and the file is: "C:\Users/Delta/Documents/maya/2023/scripts\CoDMayaTools.py". Which file have you changed instead?

Comment: Edit and change the file: "C:\Users/Delta/Documents/maya/2023/scripts\CoDMayaTools.py"

Comment: Yes that is the .py file i was editing

Comment: Then RUN it to update it's compiled version. Maybe maya uses the compiled file version without updating it to the changed script file.

Comment: Look into `[__pycache__]` directory in `[C:\Users/Delta/Documents/maya/2023/scripts\]` to delete the old compiled version of the `CoDMayaTools.py` file which is usually named `CoDMayaTools.pyc`